# JSON Schema Syntax Checker

Tags: python, json, django, validation

I need to make a JSON schema to json validator web app using Django. I've already made the UI with login features and somewhere to upload files and now I'm working on the main logic. I'm going through different ideas on how to implement it and I wondering if there was a way I could implement [jsonschema](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) into my project.  This is just an idea and I'm not sure if I should do that or just make a validator from scratch.

Also I'm using Django 1.11 with Python 2.7

Comment: First of all I do not really understand why you have to log in to check JSON syntax, furthermore I think checking the syntax is probably better suited at the frontend, and hence with JavaScript.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have a specific schema's in my website. When you register, you also pick which schema you use. For the purposes of my project, the users will ever need to compare to one schema. Also I have to do it in python 2.  Would've preferred to do the whole project in php, html, css, js no framework personally.

Comment: You might still want to validate on frontend, passing the appropriate schema once logged in -- assuming the schema isn't huge.  Especially if you'd rather use js.

Comment: @JeffLearman What do you mean when you say "passing the appropriate schema once logged in". The idea I had was to have my schemas in my filepath and have the user simply submit a JSON. And isn't validating front end super insecure and bad practice?

Comment: Good point about security; I withdraw my comment.  While it's efficient to validate on the front end to avoid wasting server time on malformed input, it's not sufficient.